# Laravel adding auth to a route returns undefined varaible

Tags: php, laravel

I have a route which was working perfectly.

```
Route::get('/advertise', 'AdvertisementController@index')->middleware('auth');
```

When i added the middleware and tried to access the advertise page i got the following error.

> Undefined variable: user (View: C:\Users\andre\Dropbox\College\Project\Rentable\resources\views\layouts\main.blade.php

This is the main layout

```
<header>
      <div class="container"><a class="logo" href="/">Rentable</a>
        <nav>
          @guest
          <a href="/register">Register</a>
          <a href="/login">Login</a>
          <a href="/advertise">Advertise Your Property</a>

          @else
          <a href="/advertise">Advertise Your Property</a>
          <a href="/account">{{$user->name}}</a>
          <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
              onclick="event.preventDefault();
                       document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
              Logout
          </a>

          <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
              {{ csrf_field() }}
          </form>
          @endguest
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

This is the index of the advert controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\PropertyAdvert;
use DB;
use Auth;

class AdvertisementController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      return view('pages/Advert/create');
    }
}
```

Comment: you are accessing `{{$user->name}}` but where you have defined it?

Comment: To access {{ $user }} on multiple pages I'd suggest looking into ComposerServiceProviders (if your `$user` is being called on multiple pages) as your controller isn't defining it.

Comment: why not {{ Auth::user()->name }} ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller code to match the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\PropertyAdvert;
use DB;
use Auth;

class AdvertisementController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      return view('pages/Advert/create', [
         'user' => Auth::user(),
      ]);
    }
}
```

You have to pass the `user` to the view in order to use it then in `{{ $user->name}}`

Alternatively if your `$user` is being passed to numerous pages take a look at composer service providers here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/providers